# Groovy code simplification and 'if' elimination

Tags: if-statement, groovy

I've the following piece of code:

```
    def avatar = avatarsService.avatar(logged, userId).get()

    def result

    if (avatar.success) {
        def url = avatar.content.avatarUrl

        if (url) {
            def content = contentForAvatar(url)
            result = content ? prepareAvatarSuccessResponse(content, avatar.content.fileType) : prepareAvatarErrorResponse(INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
        } else {
            result = prepareAvatarErrorResponse(NOT_FOUND)
        }
    } else {
        result = prepareAvatarErrorResponse(INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
    }

    result
```

First of all I need to fetch avatar description from `userService` and then process the content if it's valid (`success`). I don't like this construction? Does somebody have and idea how it can be simplified?

Answer (score 2):

Invert the output of your `avatarsService.avatar(logged, userId).get()`, so it has an `error` field instead of success. The values of this field would be `NOT_FOUND` and `INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR`.

```
def avatar = avatarsService.avatar(logged, userId).get()

def result = avatar.error ? prepareAvatarErrorResponse( avatar.error ) : 
                            prepareAvatarSuccessResponse(content, avatar.content.fileType)
```

Comment: Nice. Will investigate.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you want to change your programming paradigm : It is

## Logic Programming .

Anyway , we can based on powerful of closures:

```
ifElse(success){
    ifElse(avatar.content.avatarUrl){
         //thanks to delegate , "it" equals now to avatar.content.avatarUrl
         def content = contentForAvatar(it)
         result=content?prepareAvatarSuccessResponse(content, avatar.content.fileType) : prepareAvatarErrorResponse(INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
    }{
         result = prepareAvatarErrorResponse(NOT_FOUND)
    }
}{
      result = prepareAvatarErrorResponse(INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
}
```

**Helper Method :**

```
def ifElse(def test,Closure c,Closure ifnot={}){
     if(test){
          c.delegate=test;
          c();
        }else{
         ifnot.delegate=test;
         ifnot();

    }
}
```

## [DEMO](http://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/5717271485874176)

- Two advantages here:

  1. there is no `else` between closures .
  2. Get rid of some var declaration(def url)basing on passed argumentto closure (via delegate).

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use Groovy `switch`:

```
def avatar = avatarsService.avatar(logged, userId)
switch(avatar) {
    case {!it.success}:           return error(INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
    case {!it.content.url}:       return error(NOT_FOUND)
    case {!it.retrieveContent()}: return error(INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
    default:                      return success(avatar.retrieveContent(), avatar.content.fileType)
}
```

I renamed the prepare methods to just `error` and `success` for readability. I also added the method `retrieveContent` to the avatar. If used this way, be careful to not read the contents twice.

Answer (score 1):

I creted solution based on map of actions creating responses:

```
def avatar = avatarsService.avatar(logged, userId).get()
if (!avatar.success) {
        return prepareAvatarErrorResponse(INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
}
def map = [
        [true, true] : {prepareAvatarSuccessResponse(content, avatar.content.fileType)},
        [true, false] : {prepareAvatarErrorResponse(INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)}].withDefault {prepareAvatarErrorResponse(NOT_FOUND)}
return map[[ (url = avatar.content.avatarUrl) as boolean, contentForAvatar(url) as boolean]]()
```

Some things could be improved.